# Python: get key event and output something else

Tags: python, c, output, stdin, getchar

Using Python and C (or just Python) how can I receive every pressed key from the keyboard while my program is running and output to the screen other key? For example, if user inputs 'F' it outputs 'ph'.

Thank you

Comment: What kind of a problem are you solving? Is this an input method, a game, something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`msvcrt.getch()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getch) to get the key, and then map that to a value in a dictionary:

```
from msvcrt import getch

chars = {b'f': 'ph'}  # You could easily extend this dictionary.

while True:
    z = getch()
    if z in chars:
        print(chars[z])
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean `chars.keys():`?

Comment: @Calpratt No. When you do `in` against a dictionary it searches against keys automatically. You don't need to explicitly get the keys.

Comment: Oops. Right you are.. p2.7 is getting me into trouble again

Comment: Thank you very much! What means the "b" within the dictionary?

Comment: @user3050910 `getch()` sends bytes. The `b` cruft around the string represesents bytes, that's all that is.